# Sqlite3 / Python -- increment column by 1 using '?' and UPDATE, getting syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a python script that counts artists in a playlist and uses a SQL table to keep track of the counts.

But I keep getting syntax errors when I try to write an UPDATE call that uses a variable for the week column.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('rcg_test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
week = "this_week"
artist = "Steve"
x = (week, week, artist,)
c.execute('UPDATE stats SET (?)= ((?) + 1) WHERE name=?;', x)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

... where the first two '?' should be the name of the week column.

Instead I'm getting:

> "OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"

It works fine if I put "this_week" in directly, and the variable call works for "name=".

Comment: It's good that you're trying to use prepared statements in your Python code.  But, column names can't be parameters.  So, you'd need to do something like `SET some_col = ? + 1 ...`

Comment: ahh thanks! do you have a better way to do what i'm trying to do (assuming it's clear what i'm trying to do)?

Comment: Can you show us what the raw query would look like?  You'll have to specify the column, there isn't really a way around this (well...you _could_ just have separate statements).

Comment: In your code, the `UPDATE` statement has the column name in brackets. That would cause a syntax error. I think it should read `...SET ? = (? + 1) WHERE ...`

Comment: You can't use parameters to set a column name. That's *the whole point of parameters*, to **prevent** specifying SQL objects or other SQL syntax in parameter values. Only values are supported.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean by 'raw query'? because what i have up there is verbatim what's in my code. (im pretty new to SQL)

Comment: `c.execute('UPDATE stats SET {0}= {0} + 1 WHERE name=?;'.format(week), (artist,))`, and be **absolutely certain** that `week` is never sourced from user data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so how are you supposed to write a function that can work on multiple columns? that's the entire point of variables!

Comment: @steadynappin: you generate your own SQL based on those multiple columns. SQL parameters are **not the same thing as variables in programming languages**, their point is to help prevent SQL injection attacks, and allow the database engine to cache query plans as an optimisation (not all database engines do).